# Why is it I can't pass the reference to another function even when the readlock has not been dropped?

Tags: rust, locking, mutex, lifetime

Referring to the following code below :

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::RwLock;
    
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum RespType<'a> {
    SimpleString(&'a str),
    RespError((&'a str, &'a str)),
    Integer(i32),
    BulkString(Option<&'a str>),
    Array(Vec<RespType<'a>>),
}
    
type Db<'a> = RwLock<HashMap<&'a str, RespType<'a>>>;
pub trait KeyValueStore<'a> {
    fn get_value<'b>(&'a self, key: &'b str, callback: &'a dyn Fn(&'a RespType<'a>));
    fn set_value(&'a mut self, key: &'a str, value: RespType<'a>) -> &'a RespType<'a>;
}
    
impl<'a> KeyValueStore<'a> for Db<'a> {
    fn get_value<'b>(&'a self, key: &'b str, callback: &'a dyn Fn(&'a RespType<'a>)) {
        static null_bulk_string:RespType = RespType::BulkString(None);
        let guard = self.read().unwrap();
        let result = guard.get(key);
        match result{
            Some(v) => {callback(v)}
            None => {callback(&null_bulk_string)}
        };
    }
    
    fn set_value(&'a mut self, key: &'a str, value: RespType<'a>) -> &'static RespType<'static> {
        static ok: RespType = RespType::SimpleString("OK");
        (*self.get_mut().unwrap()).insert(key, value).unwrap();
        &ok
    }
}
    
fn main(){
    
}
```

The error message is this:

```
error[E0597]: `guard` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:22
   |
19 | impl<'a> KeyValueStore<'a> for Db<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
23 |         let result = guard.get(key);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `guard` is borrowed for `'a`
...
28 |     }
   |     - `guard` dropped here while still borrowed
```

The readlock is dropped at the end of get_value but I can't seem to pass it into callback which clearly doesn't have a lifetime that extends past the readlock. What's going on? Also I don't understand what the error message is trying to say. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going a bit overboard with the lifetime annotations, which is tying things together that you don't intend to be tied together.  Look at the signature of `get_value`:

```
fn get_value<'b>(&'a self, key: &'b str, callback: &'a dyn Fn(&'a RespType<'a>));
```

This requires that the lifetime of the borrow given to the callback function must be valid as long as the borrow of `self`, but it isn't.  This is why the error message specifically says "argument requires that `guard` is borrowed for `'a`" (which is actually an *impossible* condition to satisfy, as `self` also has lifetime `'a` and any guard obtained from `self` won't live as long as `self`).

The solution is to simply *not* bind these lifetimes together:

```
fn get_value<'b>(&'a self, key: &'b str, callback: &dyn Fn(&RespType));
```

With this signature, [the code compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ccb9620d07cdb7aab086db2b0e729ad).

I would suggest taking a step back and trying to figure out what you're trying to convey with the lifetime annotations.  It looks like you're just sprinkling them everywhere without understanding exactly what they do -- why does `get_value` need the `'b` annotation on the `key` argument, for example?